Solaar does not install!
I am a relatively newbie. Soolar installation does not work I get: "WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: INIT" when I try to install SOLAAR.
I run Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 with 64 bits OS type and 24 Gb RAM.
Please help me! What is wrong?
Extremely thankful for help.

How are you trying to install "Soolar"? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Major props for reading the messages and stopping because they are scary! You are likely trying to install the package from somewhere other than the default repos. Please edit your question with details.
